# StackOverflowError at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator on Firebase setValue() call

Tags: java, android, listener, event-listener

I am getting a StackOverflowError in my ValueEventListener and I'm not exactly sure why since I remove the listener. It seems like it's something to do with the call to setValue(). Here is the code

```
    public void joinGame(final String gameId)
    {
        System.out.println("join");
        mtGames.child(gameId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                Game game = snapshot.getValue(Game.class);
                game.addPlayer(mProfile);
                mProfile.setGame(game);
                mtGames.child(gameId).setValue(mProfile.getGame()); // The error occurs on this line
                mtGames.removeEventListener(this);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Could it be the kind of listener I'm using? One idea I had was that since it's an addValueEventListener, it keeps getting called since I'm adding an element into the database in onDataChange(). However, I don't see this behavior reflected in my database, the code block doesn't appear to get called more than once, and I remove the listener. I'm not really sure why this is happening.

Here is the console output:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: skateboard.skate, PID: 10127
    java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8192KB
        at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.<init>(HashMap.java:1423)
        at java.util.HashMap$ValueIterator.<init>(HashMap.java:1468)
        at java.util.HashMap$Values.iterator(HashMap.java:968)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:652)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:167)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(CustomClassMapper.java:47)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:675)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:167)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(CustomClassMapper.java:47)
...
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:675)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:167)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(CustomClassMapper.java:47)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:675)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:167)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToPlainJavaTypes(CustomClassMapper.java:60)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValueInternal(DatabaseReference.java:282)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValue(DatabaseReference.java:159)
        at skateboard.skate.MainActivity$2.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:155)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8125)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting infinite recursion, which erodes your stack space.

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    Game game = snapshot.getValue(Game.class);
    game.addPlayer(mProfile);
    mProfile.setGame(game);
    mtGames.child(gameId).setValue(mProfile.getGame()); // <-- changes data, triggering onDataChange to be invoked.
    mtGames.removeEventListener(this); // <-- happens too late.
}
```

A fix might be something like:

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    Game game = snapshot.getValue(Game.class);
    if (mProfile.getGame() != game)
    {
        game.addPlayer(mProfile);
        mProfile.setGame(game);
        mtGames.child(gameId).setValue(mProfile.getGame());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm... I thought this would work, but nothing changes when I implement this idea.

Comment: The event listener removed was wrong.  Fixed in the sample code...

Comment: Still, the same behavior occurs.

Comment: I think I need more info - i.e. what are you trying to achieve with the listener?